# trying to compile boost dependent library - "is private" error

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile https://code.google.com/p/feed-reader-lib/ but on Feed.cpp it gives me a strange error.

```
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/recursive_mutex.hpp:40:9: error: ‘boost::recursive_mutex::recursive_mutex(const boost::recursive_mutex&)’ is private
Feed.cpp:49:69: error: within this context
```

I am yet too unfamiliar with C++, so I absolutely cannot explain what could be wrong here, since the Compiler raises this error at the declaration state. Nothing about the above library that could be wrong - rather, it seems to me, that the boost library is wrong (in that it wrongly makes `boost::recursive_mutex::recursive_mutex(const boost::recursive_mutex&)` private). But surely that cannot be the case.

What am I missing out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you get means that there is an attempt to copy a non-copyable `recursive_mutex`. Open `Feed.cpp` and change the following line:

```
boost::recursive_mutex Feed::m_stateMutex = boost::recursive_mutex();
```

To this:

```
boost::recursive_mutex Feed::m_stateMutex;
```